# Who did first use the concept of "supremum"?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, math-history

Is there one specific person, who first defined the concept of "supremum"? If so: In which work?

In my textbooks or by a quick search on the internet, I did not find an answer to my question.

Comment: Maybe it was first defined by Bolzano in 1817, in *Reinanalytischer Beweisdes Lehrsatzes, dass zwischenjezweiWerthen,
die ein entgegengesetztes Resultat gewähren, wenigstens eine reelle Wurzel der
Gleichung liege*, see Wanner, Hairer - Analysis by its history, p. 182.

Comment: @Hakim, also in page 175 of *A History of Analysis*, edited by Hans Niels Jahnke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(To answer this question so that it doesn't stay in the unanswered list)*

> Maybe it was first defined by Bolzano in 1817, in *Reinanalytischer Beweisdes Lehrsatzes, dass zwischenjezweiWerthen, die ein entgegengesetztes Resultat gewähren, wenigstens eine reelle Wurzel der Gleichung liege*, see Wanner, Hairer - Analysis by its history, p. 182.
>
> also in page 175 of A History of Analysis, edited by Hans Niels Jahnke. –  [lhf](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/589/lhf)